# How to check the defined error class of a connection?

Tags: sybase, sybase-rs

How to check the defined error class of a connection (DSI) of Sybase Replication Server?

I use `alter connection` to change the error class associated to the DSI but I want a command that list its information in order to confirm that the error class was correctly associated.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see it by calling `rs_getconn` in the RSSD database.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any rs_getconn stored proc in an RSSD database for a 15.7.1 repserver.

I do see a ral_connection_details proc which seems to do the job (example output connecting with sqsh):

```
> ral_connection_details "MY_ASE_SERVER", "MyDB"; -mvert
dsname:                MY_ASE_SERVER
dbname:                MyDB
error class:           rs_sqlserver_error_class
function string class: rs_sqlserver_function_class
username:              mylogin
password:              NULL    -- Note, the password *isn't* null, whatever
dbid:                  123
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where rs_getconn and ral_connection_details came from (3rd party app? custom proc? one of a slew of fly-by-night SRS management tools Sybase provided over the years?), but the simplest (and guaranteed to be in any RSSD going back eons - unless someone dropped it) is the **rs_helpdb** stored proc.

**rs_helpdb** generates a result set showing dsname, dbname, did, prs, error and function classes; for RS 15.7+ you'll also get connid (associated with multipath rep / alternate connections) and the repserver error class.